# How do I pre-install Ubuntu for someone (OEM install)?

Tags: system-installation, oem

I would like to pre-install Ubuntu on a computer for someone. I may want to customize it for them, but in the end they need to be able to choose a username, password, etc. when they first boot it up. (Also called an OEM install).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I originally thought this feature was only available in the alternate installer but I have been corrected. I was able to boot up a USB key for the desktop CD, holding down the left shift key until I was asked to choose a language, and then I hit <kbd>F4</kbd> and was presented with this menu:

[image]

Colin Watson also notes that you can enable `oem-config/enable=true` as a [boot parameter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter) to expose the feature. After using it it prompted me with OEM-looking prompts:

[image]

If you are using the [alternate installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads) you can just hit <kbd>F4</kbd> and choose OEM Install right from the first screen:

[image]

Comment: Is there a link with the packages called OEM-config-something? How to use it after installing them. I was wondering what was the use of OEM-config-remaster. I try to customize an ISO and the packages, it's why I wonder that.

Answer (score 59):

### Use the built-in *OEM install* functionality!

It's very easy to install Ubuntu on a computer for someone else, so that you can customize it for their needs but they can still perform the final basic setup (username, password, language, etc.).

#### Phase 1. Pre-installation

**1 (Updated for Ubuntu 20.04 UEFI).**

Make sure to  boot from the installation USB in the UEFI mode. You will see the screen below. If you don't see this grub menu, then you did not boot in the UEFI mode from the USB.

Select **OEM install (for Manufacturer)** as shown below:

[image]

1. (**For BIOS/Legacy/CSM installs (untested in Ubuntu 20.04)**) Press any key to interrupt the LiveCD/LiveUSB autoboot; then press <kbd>F4</kbd> and select *OEM Install*, and then "Install Ubuntu"

[image]

**The rest of the process is pretty much the same as below.**

2. Enter a "company name" (it will only be used in error reports, etc.)

[image]

3. Continue installing...

[image]

4. Enter a temporary username, password and machine-name for the *customization phase*

[image]

5. Restart

[image]

###Phase 2. Customization

6. You are now in the *customization phase:*

[image]

7. **Perform customization:** Upgrades, updates, install software, remove software, change wallpapers, etc. In the sample below, we just use the terminal to change the Ubuntu update mirror to one closer to New York City.

[image]

8. When you are done, close all windows and double-click on the *Prepare for shipping to end-user* icon on the desktop, which will show the message as below:

[image]

###Phase 3. End-user configuration/"installation"

9. When the receiver first boots up the computer, he/she will have to select a language:

[image]

10. ...and their location/time zone...

[image]

11. ...and keyboard layout...

[image]

12. They then choose their username, password, machine-name and whether to encrypt their home directory:

[image]

13. Ubuntu takes a few seconds to perform these final customizations...

[image]

14. ...and takes the user **directly to their new login screen!**

[image]

Comment: Note that if you forgot to run setup in OEM mode, you can still run `sudo apt-get install oem-config` and then `oem-config-prepare`.

Answer (score 31):

When the boot menu comes up all you have to do is select "Install in OEM Mode" then walk through the rest of the process.

Here is more detailed instructions with screen shots:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview

Here is a screenshot of this option from Ubuntu 12.04 installation. You need to *press a key* to bring this option menu just after starting to boot the Live CD or USB.

[image]

Comment: Wow that page could do with an update!?

Comment: @Allan yeah but it should still apply...

Comment: Also, it is a wiki. Once you figure out how exactly you did it, then update the wiki page. This way you will contribute to the ubuntu community as well.

Comment: @Joshua which is why I plus one'd your answer ;)

Comment: This answer is correct. Yeah, the screenshots look ancient, but the actual documentation and steps are correct. I did that for one of my laptops when I gave it away to a friend.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, this is exactly what I needed. I ran into some problems along the way and will update the Wiki page in the link tonight.

Firstly, I could not find this option in the Ubuntu Desktop image, I had to use the ALTERNATE image. You must press F4 on the selection screen, and highlight "OEM Mode". Secondly, if you are booting from a USB drive, you must press F6, tick "Expert mode", press esc to close that menu, press tab to edit the boot options, and add this to the end: cdrom-detect/try-
usb=true

Couldn't get it to work from an SD card.

Comment: @Gleasonator sorry I wasn't aware how much the process had changed if at all (haven't done it in forever, but I am glad you were able to figure it out.

Comment: Does it work for Ubuntu 12.04 too?

Comment: it works on 12.04 desktop. http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIpgX.png