# In OEM Installations can we edit final-user applications setting?

Tags: installation, oem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make an OEM Install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36671/how-to-make-an-oem-install)

In OEM Installations can we edit final-user applications setting with the OEM-User to change the final user settings?
if possible how can I do?