# Run a script only at the very first boot

Tags: boot, scripts, amazon-ec2

Is there an idiomatic way in Ubuntu to run a script only the first time a machine is booted? (EC2).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No. But you might want to place your script in `/etc/init.d/script`, and self-delete it:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Bump! I'm your first-boot script."

# Delete self
rm "${0}"
```

Comment: Please note, `$0` is bash-specific (version >= 3). For compatibility purpose you can provide script file name instead, making this less generic: `rm /etc/init.d/script`

Comment: $0 is NOT bash specific and it has been supported for far longer than bash 3.x has been around (and it's supported in Bourne, Korn, zsh and others).  The sticking point is whether $0 contains a full or relative path specification.  Here's a link to a reliable way of getting the full path if you need it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774054/reliable-way-for-a-bash-script-to-get-the-full-path-to-itself

Comment: @andrejs-cainikovs It doesn't seem to work on systemd systems such as Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Answer (score 12):

Combining the first two answers
Assuming you name your script `/usr/local/bin/firstboot.sh` put it at the end of `/etc/rc.local` (this scripts runs on every boot) the scripts goes like this

Update 2022: Put the script in crontab like this

```
@reboot /usr/local/bin/firstboot.sh
```

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

FLAG="/var/log/firstboot.log"
if [[ ! -f $FLAG ]]; then
   #Put here your initialization sentences
   echo "This is the first boot"
   
   #the next line creates an empty file so it won't run the next boot
   touch "$FLAG"
else
   echo "Do nothing"
fi
```

Comment: This is not necessarily working with sysmtemd. I need to add a sleep 20 to make sure it is the last script run.

Comment: If you name it /etc/rc.local/99-firstboot.sh it should run last.

Comment: @JohnDavid Creating a `/etc/rc.local/99-firstboot.sh` script didn't work after reboot.

Comment: Make sure your script is executable. Check syslog for crontab errors.  You should see something like this  `Feb  5 12:43:31 madeleine cron[1432]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)`

Answer (score 9):

Create a tracking file when the script runs. If the file already exists, exit the script.

Comment: While it might not seem so at first glance, this may be a better solution than deleting the script as it retains the possibility to trigger it again, should you ever want to.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, it was building a custom system and I had to refuse to use cloud-init and placing a script under `/etc/init.d/script` didn't work - so I used systemd.

FILE  `/etc/systemd/system/firstboot.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=One time boot script
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/firstboot.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and

FILE `/firstboot.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash 
SOME COMMANDS YOU WANT TO EXECUTE
systemctl disable firstboot.service 
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/firstboot.service
rm -f /firstboot.sh
```

Then enable

```bash
sudo chmod +x /firstboot.sh
sudo systemctl enable firstboot.service
```

This one works just fine for me.

Comment: You just need to add the directory names and filenames for the files you created.

Comment: note that commands I've posted are `echo "sth" > filename`. The output of echo command is directed to a specific file with filename (if the file doesn't exist then it's created)

Comment: Okay for clarity changed this. :)

Comment: @adam-krawczyk Thanks a lot for this solution that works SystemD Linux.

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised at the results I'm seeing for searching for a well-defined and supported Ubuntu "first boot" hook.  Seems like the Red Hat / Fedora / CentOS crowd has had this nailed for over a decade.  The closest Ubuntu equivalent seems to be [oem-config-firstboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36671/how-do-i-pre-install-ubuntu-for-someone-oem-install).

The idea of simply performing an `rm $0` will work.  But, technically there are some interesting semantics involved.  Unlike most other script interpreters under Unix a shell script is read and processed one line/statement at a time.  If you unlink (`rm`) the file out from under it then that the instance of the shell that's processing that script is now working with an anonymous file (any file that's open but unlinked).

Consider a file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm $0
echo "I've removed myself: $0"
ls -l $0
cat <<COMMENTARY
   This is a test.
   I'm still here, because the "here" doc is being fed to 'cat'
   via the anonymous file through the open file descriptor.
   But I cannot be re-exec'd
COMMENTARY
exec $0
```

If you save that to something like `rmself.sh` and (hard) link that to something like `tst` then running `./tst` should show something like this as output:

```
$ ./tst 
I've removed myself: ./tst
ls: ./tst: No such file or directory
   This is a test.
   I'm still here, because the "here" doc is being fed to 'cat'
   via the anonymous file through the open file descriptor.
   But I cannot be re-exec'd
./tst: line 11: /home/jimd/bin/tst: No such file or directory
./tst: line 11: exec: /home/jimd/bin/tst: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Now there are some odd possible corner cases with regards to symlinks and cases where the script was invoked as a bare name (forcing the shell to search the `$PATH` for the script.

But it seems that `bash` (at least in version 3.2) prepends `$0` with the path if it searched the path and otherwise leaves $0 set to whatever relative or absolute path was used to invoke the script.  It doesn't seem to do any normalization or resolution relative paths nor symlinks.

Probably the cleanest "firstboot" for Ubuntu would be to create a small package (.deb) containing a script to be placed in `/etc/init.d/firstboot` and a post-install script that uses `update-rc.d` to link that into runlevel 1 (`/etc/rc1.d`) (using a command like: `update-rc.d firstboot defaults`) ... and then have the last line perform a deactivation or delete using something like: `update-rc.d firstboot disable`

Here's a link to the [Debian update-rc.d HOWTO](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-managing-services-with-update-rc-d/)

Answer (score 3):

The question was about running a script at first boot of EC2.
You can use `cloud-init` for this purpose.

When launching a new EC2 instance you have an option to define `User data` under `Advanced datails`. If you place `cloud-init` script there, it will be executed at first boot only.

For example you can place the following in `User data`:

```
#cloud-config

runcmd:
  - /usr/bin/command1.sh
  - /usr/bin/command2.sh
```

The output will be written to `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`

`Cloud-init` can do much more than this. It is designed especially to perform early initialization of cloud instances. See the docs here: http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can backup current rc.local to rc.local.bak

Then you can have the stuff you want to do in rc.local and at the end just mv /etc/rc.loca.bak /etc/rc.local.