# No WiFi or Enable WiFi option after restart Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, dell, iwlwifi

Please help me troubleshoot this WiFi issue with my laptop. I have a Dell XPS L521X running on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. My WiFi card is **Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260**. My WiFi would work normally, but on a random cold startup or restart, the WiFi does not work (hollow WiFi icon and no Enable WiFi option available).

Running `sudo service network-manager restart` makes it work again, but I don't want to do that every time I restart the computer. Any ideas how to troubleshoot this?

Just in case, here is what I get when ran a few commands to check on the status:

```
han@XPS:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    3.714166] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.716989] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.753941] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[    3.754221] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[    3.754835] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[    3.977124] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    3.978658] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0 wlp8s0: renamed from wlan0
[    4.192308] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[    4.192568] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[    4.394290] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[    4.394697] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
han@XPS:~$ modinfo iwlwifi | grep 7260
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode
han@XPS:~$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 07
       serial: f0:1f:af:32:ce:79
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:29 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d2404000-d2404fff memory:d2400000-d2403fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlp8s0
       version: 73
       serial: 7c:5c:f8:68:e7:e6
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-22-generic firmware=16.242414.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:34 memory:d2600000-d2601fff
han@XPS:~$ sudo service network-manager restart
han@XPS:~$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 07
       serial: f0:1f:af:32:ce:79
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:29 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d2404000-d2404fff memory:d2400000-d2403fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlp8s0
       version: 73
       serial: 7c:5c:f8:68:e7:e6
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-22-generic firmware=16.242414.0 ip=192.168.1.9 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:34 memory:d2600000-d2601fff
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this happen on restart, or after hibernation, or suspend? I am using the same adapter, and it happens only after hibernation.

Comment: It doesn't happen on suspend or sleep (closing lid), only on fresh startup or restart.

Comment: This is likely a bug in network-manager, see if `nmcli -f all device show | sed '/^GENERAL.DEVICE:[ ]\+lo$/,/^$/d; /^AP\[[0-9]\+\]\./d'` shows the Intel device as ethernet

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick hacky way to achieve the result you want.  Open up your `~/.bashrc` file with a text editor and scroll to the bottom and add the line `echo "your_password" | sudo service network-manager restart`.  This will be run automatically every time you turn on your computer.  A bad side effect though is that it will be run every time you open a new terminal window as well.  Another more elegant option is to put it in a script like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156771/run-a-script-only-at-the-very-first-boot) so it is only run on startup.

Comment: Thanks, but no luck. I added a file `/etc/init.d/wifi` and chmod 755 it. I've added the `echo "mypassword" | sudo service network-manager restart` to it with the auto delete code like the one in your link. It doesn't run like it should. I can manually run it from the terminal.

Comment: put this in the file {#!/bin/bash echo "your_password" | sudo service network-manager restart # Delete me rm $0} and change the password to your user password

Comment: Please see my edited post above. No luck for me.