# Wifi not connecting after restart in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless

After upgrading to 16.04, the wifi is not connecting whenever I restart the system. It shows 'device not ready'.  My Wireless interface of Ubuntu is RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe

on iwconfig I got the following

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Currently to start wifi again I have to shutdown, then boot the system again.

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

or

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

doesn't starts wifi.

How to fix the problem?.

Comment: I doubt it, Shutdown and Reboot are exactly identical ! Are you really rebooting?

Comment: @Sharad Gautam  Yep. when I shut down and restart, then no problem. If I restart directly, then no wifi.

Comment: This too related http://askubuntu.com/questions/761180/wifi-doesnt-work-after-suspend-after-16-04-upgrade/761220#761220

Comment: This my friend is a common problem with many Wifi Adapters. Even with my Windows 10 system (using windows 7 drivers. All you can try is installing different drivers. Good Luck!

Comment: Disable Secure Boot.

Comment: @Pilot6 it is already disabled

Comment: this one also releated  http://askubuntu.com/questions/777516/no-wifi-or-enable-wifi-option-after-restart-ubuntu-16-04