# HP bs179tx Wifi not working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I am using HP bs179tx.

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 but I am not able to get my Wifi working.

It has Realtek driver installed in it

I do not see the option Enable Wifi in the network bar.

Comment: Try shutdown, then boot the system again (not restart). See this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/791945/wifi-not-connecting-after-restart-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: 1. Can you post the contents of `dmesg`?

Answer (score 1):

The HP BS179TX laptop comes with Realtek WiFi Hardware. The
Network controller is **Realtek Semiconductor RTL8723DE Device d723**.

The linux driver for this device is not directly available.
But, according to the discussion "[Realtek 8723DE wifi module](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/Realtek-8723DE-wifi-module-amp-Bluetooth-Linux-driver/td-p/6477307)" in HP Support Forum, the RTL8723DE officially supported driver is made available in the repo : [rtlwifi-new git extended branch](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/#a-repo-for-the-newest-realtek-rtlwifi-codes) .

You can find the installation instructions [here](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/#installation-instruction)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers) . The wifi drivers might be deactivated. You have to enable it manually.