# wifi is not working in my hp laptop 15-bs580TX FOR Ubuntu

Tags: wireless

am using hp laptop 15-bs580TX
my os is ubuntu 17.10
wifi option is not displaying 
how to fix this?
my wifi adapter is realtek
plz help me

Comment: Try shutdown, then boot the system again ( not restart). See this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/791945/wifi-not-connecting-after-restart-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Please edit to include results for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the drivers are deactivated. 
To fix this Go to

> Settings > Software sources(15.10) or Software & updates (later versions) > Go to Additional Drivers tab > Click on USE radio button of the respective wifi driver.

You can also refer [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers) for more details.