# How do I install Ubuntu on someone's laptop so they can customize it?

Tags: installation, software-recommendation, live-usb, live-cd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make an OEM Install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36671/how-to-make-an-oem-install)

I would like to give someone an old computer ("hand-me-down") after installing Ubuntu on it. Is there a way to preinstall and/or customize it for the user so that they can do the final setup (username, password, etc.) themselves?