# I want to sell my computer, how can I "preinstall" Ubuntu without configuring it?

Tags: system-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I pre-install Ubuntu for someone (OEM install)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36671/how-do-i-pre-install-ubuntu-for-someone-oem-install)

I basically want to install the installer, so that when the computer boots it will boot into the installer from the hard driver. I am selling my computer and I want a fresh copy of Ubuntu to be on it when the buyer receives it. How can I do this?