# Install ubuntu like it was bought at a store

Tags: system-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I pre-install Ubuntu for someone (OEM install)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36671/how-do-i-pre-install-ubuntu-for-someone-oem-install)

When you buy a computer the first time you start it up you create an account for it.  Is there anyway to have this happen when you install ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the OEM install mode by hitting F4 in the boot splash of the install CD. See also: http://www.logicsupply.com/blog/2012/03/21/how-to-create-a-custom-ubuntu-12-04-installation-image/ - just skip the clonezilla parts.