# Cloning Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, clone

I have 200 windows 7 laptops that were just delivered.  I have a test laptop that I have setup with ubuntu.  What is the best way to clone the new laptops to exactly match the identical ubuntu ( setup the way I want ) laptop.

I've tried many things:
1) DRBL will not load because it cannot find the imp file ( I had great hopes for this one )

2) FOG will not run on ext

Comment: Can you use [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/)?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/228687/difference-between-oem-install-and-custom-ubuntu-image for some alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I clone many machines in my work and I have great success with simply using tar from the command line.

Mount the partition of the source hard drive to (say) /mnt.

tar cvfpz /home/me/documents/mybackup.tar.gz /mnt

I recreate the partitions on the new HDD. Untar my Tarball to the new partition and re install grub.

Mount new hard drive to /mnt

cd /

tar xvfpz /my back up.tar.gz

All in all it is relatively quick and painless.