# How to install Ubuntu on more than one machines with same configuration?

Tags: system-installation, software-installation

I'm planning to install Ubuntu 14.04 (32-bit) on about 25 computers, but that place doesn't have internet access, so I have to install a lot of packages in every machine. (Need to install JDK, GNU C++ Compiler and others)

1. Is there anyway to create a basic setup with all the required packages preinstalled and then install OS in all of them?
2. Is there anyway to install Ubuntu in all machines at the same time assuming all machines have same configuration. (and What if it has different configuration?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd)

Comment: Also try [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) or [Fog](http://www.fogproject.org/).

Comment: For an really low-tech solution, write a small script which does the installation of the needed packages

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/228687/difference-between-oem-install-and-custom-ubuntu-image/228754#228754

Answer (score 0):

I would say the easiest thing to do would be to install Ubuntu and all of the packages on to a main hard drive.

Then clone that hard drive, maybe use CloneZilla and rip an image of it. Once said Image is ripped CloneZilla should let you use the image and distribute it to several hard drives at once, (given they are all in the same computer). So if a single computer has 4 or 5 sata ports, you could throw out the image to 4 or 5 hard drives at once that would have the same config and packages loaded.

http://clonezilla.org/

If you are unsure how to use this software, read up on it. Plenty of information on the site and lots more if you just Google it as well. Hope this might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in multiple ways:

1. Make your own custom Ubuntu distro using remastersys or [relinux](https://launchpad.net/relinux) or ...
2. Setup an initial pc with all tools and apps you like then make a clone of its disk to other machines using cloning tools such as [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to perform an unattended installation perhaps this would be useful:

[How do I create a completely unattended install of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122505/how-do-i-create-a-completely-unattended-install-of-ubuntu)

It might be a little overkill for only 25 installs but it's probably your best bet, other than cloning a system.