# How can I factory-reset an OEM install of Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, oem

I have a version of Ubuntu on my laptop that came with an [OEM install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228687/difference-between-oem-install-and-custom-ubuntu-image).

However, I want to factory-reset this computer back to original settings. Meaning, the next time I boot my computer up, I'd like to go through the entire "initial setup" phase once again and get to work on a clean slate of a machine, in the exact state it was when I first took this machine out of the box.

Ideally, I'd like to do this without having to actually reinstall, instead relying on the OS to reset itself (I don't mind installing a couple packages if necessary). In essence, I'd like to run the equivalent of a Windows "Reset OS" operation on my machine.

Is such a thing possible from the OS itself? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this because I don't want to wipe my system.  However, the following *may* do what you want:

1. Create a new user:

   - Name: OEM Configuration (temporary user)
   - Login: `oem`
   - UID: 29999
   - Groups: adm, cdrom, sudo, dip, plugdev, lpadmin, oem, sambashare
   - Home: `/home/oem`
2. Log in as `oem` and delete all other users and home folders.
3. Install: `oem-config`, `oem-config-slideshow-ubuntu`, `oem-config-gtk`, `ubiquity`, `ubiquity-frontend-gtk`, `ubiquity-ubuntu-artwork`
4. Make other changes as desired.
5. Run `oem-config-prepare`