# Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 requires a user

Tags: 18.04, desktop-environments, ubuntu-gnome, preseed

Is it possible to skip user creation for Ubuntu Desktop?

I know this is possible for Ubuntu Server using following:

```
d-i passwd/make-user boolean false
```

I've tried the method above for Ubuntu Desktop with no success.

Comment: Aren't you just asking for the OEM install?

Comment: Perhaps I am?
I've been using `Packer` with `preseed.cfg` to build an image.
If you have the opportunity to elaborate, or refer to sources about OEM install it would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview, or on this site refer https://askubuntu.com/questions/228687/difference-between-oem-install-and-custom-ubuntu-image

Comment: @guiverc OEM install is not what I need, unfortunately. I will still face the same problem that a user needs to be created when launching the image, after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu desktop installs itself a bit different than Ubuntu server.
Ubuntu server actually builds an OS from scratch with debians from a local or web repositories, and has many many install menus and parameters to configure. That is why you usually want to use a preseed file.

Official Ubuntu desktop uses a squashfs - an existing OS that was compressed and can be used for an easy clone install. Many preseed commands you know for Ubuntu servers are not used in the process.

If you would like to completely obsolete an installation part like this and not use OEM, you are going to need a custom made squash with your own parameters and components. Something that is not always easy to be done, but achievable.

Comment: It's not like that I don't "want" to use OEM install, it's rather I would face the same exact problem, meaning: After the reboot when OEM is finished - I am asked to create a user, as I would during a normal installation.

I really like the explanation, and would take a deeper look at squashfs.