# Download Ubuntu 11.10 for Dell Vostro 3360

Tags: 11.10

Where can I download manufacturer/preinstalled version of Ubuntu 11.10 for Dell Vostro 3360?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few different options.

1. As fabricator4 mentions, you can [contact Dell](https://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/dellcare/contact_sales_support?s=dhs) and ask if they have any available for purchase.
2. You can build your own, following the instructions on [Dell's support page](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/w/linux/building-base-ubuntu-factory-iso.aspx) explaining the process. Ubuntu 11.10 images are available [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.10/).
3. You can just install any current version of Ubuntu normally. You don't need to do anything special, it's just a laptop. 12.10 is the most recent version, but 12.04 is also current and has long-term support. Both are available on the Ubuntu.com [download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).
4. If your goal is to preinstall Ubuntu in preparation for selling or giving away the computer, you can do what is called an OEM install, [explained here](https://askubuntu.com/q/36671/12864).

Your best solution is going to be either #3 or #4, as they are free and use current versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: I need a special manufacturer version because the others available on ubuntu.com does not work(for 12.04 no ethernet, scroll etc) or 11.10 does not install totally.

Answer (score 0):

Dell don't seem to have seen fit to make OEM disks of Ubuntu for the 3360 available for download on their support pages.  You could try contacting Dell support and see if they can help you.