# Ubuntu 12.04 OEM install from USB - Need help to either change boot options or add to USB without losing OEM option

Tags: system-installation

I'd like to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in OEM mode on a few desktops via usb drive.

These instructions work fine to install in OEM mode on a VM using the .iso from Ubuntu site : [How do I pre-install Ubuntu for someone (OEM install)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36671/how-do-i-pre-install-ubuntu-for-someone-oem-install)

But as soon as I add that .iso to my USB the only option that shows up when I press f4 for the advance installation modes is "normal".

I'm using rufus to add the image to my flash drive and encountering this issue. I've also tried using unetbootin and I can't seem to get the advance installation options to show up by pressing f4.

Ideally I'd like to just make a permanent change to the boot options so the image boots in OEM mode since I will use this periodically for that purpose.

If that's not an option I'd be fine with suggestions for other programs that I can use to add the image to the usb and test to see if it will still have an OEM option.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example a bootable USB key (Backtrack/Ubuntu based) made using unetbootin

```
tree -L3

.
├── autorun.inf
├── boot
│   └── grub
│       ├── efi.img
│       ├── font.pf2
│       ├── grub.cfg
│       ├── loopback.cfg
│       └── x86_64-efi
├── casper
│   ├── filesystem.manifest
│   ├── filesystem.manifest-desktop
│   ├── filesystem.manifest-remove
│   ├── filesystem.size
│   ├── filesystem.squashfs
│   ├── initrdf.gz
│   ├── initrd.gz
│   ├── initrd.lz
│   ├── initrds.gz
│   ├── README.diskdefines
│   ├── vmlinuz
│   └── vmlinuz.efi
├── EFI
│   └── BOOT
│       ├── BOOTx64.EFI
│       └── grubx64.efi
├── install
│   └── mt86plus
├── isolinux
│   ├── adtxt.cfg
│   ├── chain.c32
│   ├── dtmenu.cfg
│   ├── exithelp.cfg
│   ├── f10.txt
│   ├── f1.txt
│   ├── f2.txt
│   ├── f3.txt
│   ├── f4.txt
│   ├── f5.txt
│   ├── f6.txt
│   ├── f7.txt
│   ├── f8.txt
│   ├── f9.txt
│   ├── gfxboot.c32
│   ├── gfxboot.cfg
│   ├── isolinux.bin
│   ├── isolinux.cfg
│   ├── memtest
│   ├── menu.cfg
│   ├── po4a.cfg
│   ├── prompt.cfg
│   ├── rqtxt.cfg
│   ├── splash.png
│   ├── stdmenu.cfg
│   ├── txt.cfg
│   └── vesamenu.c32
├── ldlinux.sys
├── md5sum.txt
├── menu.c32
├── preseed
│   ├── cli.seed
│   ├── custom.seed
│   ├── ltsp.seed
│   └── ubuntu.seed
├── syslinux.cfg
├── ubnfilel.txt
├── ubninit
├── ubnkern
├── ubnpathl.txt
├── ubuntu
└── wubi.exe
```

There 3 boot configuration folders:

- /boot/grub/grub.cfg : Ubuntu original live cd boot configuration (Not used)
- /isolinux/isolinux.cfg : Backtrack live cd boot configuration (Was used by ISO)
- /syslinux.cfg : Unetbootin usb boot configuration (Used by USB, has some entries copied from ISO config by unetbootin)

All this configuration files have all most same syntax. We can just copy the entry we want to `syslinux.cfg`

As in your case it should the OEM entry:

```
label oem
menu label OEM install (for manufacturers)
linux /casper/vmlinuz
append initrd=/casper/initrd.gz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash oem-config/enable=true --
```

You can learn from isolinux how make advanced menu. Make a look on all text files there.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem several times.

To remedy the issue I used ["Universal USB Installer"](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) to create bootable flash.