# Out of Box Experience

Tags: 14.04

Does Ubuntu have an "Out of Box Experience" set up similar to Windows?  I intend to sell used PCs with Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS preinstalled and I want my customers to be able to set up their own username, password, etc.

Comment: Do an OEM install: http://askubuntu.com/questions/36671/how-do-i-pre-install-ubuntu-for-someone-oem-install

Answer (score 0):

No, however, as you are probably aware, the closest thing to an OoB experience is simply running through the install themselves.

Assuming you're not trying to install software for the customer, you could simply mount the ubuntu ISO directly to the HDD and then update grub.

Now, when the customer powers up the device, they can simply run through the install wizard, dictating their usernames/passwords/etc.

Aside from that, your 2 options are to either build an OoB experience for Ubuntu yourself, or educate the customer on how to use and customize the pre-installed OS.