# OEM Install of Ubuntu Server [14.04.3]

Tags: 14.04, server, compiling, oem

I am trying to do an OEM install of Ubuntu Server (14.04.3) but cannot seem to get it working. I have managed to do a Ubuntu Desktop (14.04.3) easily.

**Why?**

I am trying to this to:

1. Install all current updates
2. Install open-vm-tools, sssd and other packages
3. "install" some in house scripts
4. Put the initial config in for SSSD, so a custom "join-domain" script can be run which just does the final steps to test and join the domain once deployed.
5. Have a consistent base build which can be used for VM Servers.

Can someone please point me at a step by step guide to achieve this similar to the one for Desktop [OEM Installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview).

Many Thanks for your help on this.

**UPDATE** 2015-01-18: Adding step by step of what I have tried:

I tried to add images properly but I'm not allowed to, very unhelpful!!!

I have tried this:

1. Select OEM Install (for manufacturers) from installation media boot menu (Screenshot: i.stack.imgur.com/tg5WX.png)
2. Install Ubuntu Server as normal (Screenshot: i.stack.imgur.com/l4pgz.png)
3. Install Additional Packages (Screenshot: i.stack.imgur.com/me1t2.png)
4. Initial config of packages
5. Try and run oem-config-prepare (Screenshot: i.stack.imgur.com/RNHM8.png)
   **ERROR MESSAGE**
   The program 'oem-config-prepare' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: 
   sudo apt-get install oem-config

Please advise what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Per this answer: 
[How do I pre-install Ubuntu for someone (OEM install)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36671/how-do-i-pre-install-ubuntu-for-someone-oem-install/36673#36673) 
Open the **F6 Other Options** and add **oem-config/enable=true** to the boot params.

Comment: This works great for Ubuntu Desktop but not for Ubuntu Server, see edited question above.

Comment: @JoePitt Correct.  It does not work if you select the "OEM Install" menu item. You must add the statement to the boot params accessed via the "F6" menu item,