# Selling Used Laptop with Fresh Ubuntu Install. How to make it boot into config screen on first boot?

Tags: system-installation, configuration, oem

I can't seem to find a specific answer to my question.

I have some used laptops I am selling on Ebay...

What I would like to have happen is for the customer to receive the laptop and on first boot the setup process will guide them through the initial setup of the computer.

Is this what the OEM install does, or is there a way to effectively pause the install at the setup screen?

I am not looking for legal advise or an opinion. I would like to know what the recommended action is to do in this situation. I am charging only for the laptop, but I want it initially boot into a setup screen for the user.

In this situation would the OEM install be ideal?

That would be my guess, but I am certainly not the Original Equipment Manufacturer.... but as the (re)Manufacturer it seems it may apply.

Comment: I am not sure how much legal advice we can provide here. Might want to contact Ebay's legal team.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release)

Comment: I am not looking for legal advise or an opinion. I would like to know what the recommended action is to do in this situation. I am charging only for the laptop, but I want it initially boot into a setup screen for the user. Perhaps I need to update my question.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. While there is a correct answer for standard vs OEM, the answer for Current vs LTS is more opinion based.

Comment: all issues with question have been addressed... and I got the answer I was looking for below... thanks everyone for your input :)

Comment: Dupe: https://askubuntu.com/questions/36671/how-do-i-pre-install-ubuntu-for-someone-oem-install

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*OEM Install?* Yes.  When a recipient boots for the first time [they are directed to the system setup wizard](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview), to set location, keyboard layout, user name, and other specifics. You may wish to read this discussion of [OEM installs and recovery reimaging](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDownUnder/BOFs/OEMRescue).

When I refurbished desktops and laptops at [Freegeek](https://freegeek.org) in Portland [yahrens](http://www.kobol.com/archives/timeunit.html) ago, every machine sold through their Thrift Store or which went out the door to schools, non-profits, and other destinations was OEM-installed, and Freegeek (though a very worthy 501(c)(3) not-for-profit) was not a manufacturer.

**NOTE**

*Latest Ubuntu or LTS?*  If you use the 'latest' the recipient will need to upgrade in July to get support here, as [19.10 is EOL then](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EoanErmine/ReleaseNotes).  It would be a kindness to the recipient to install 18.04 LTS, which [does not reach the end of community support until April 2023](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle).

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! This is exactly what I was looking for! I have voted to reopen question... we'll see what happens

Comment: So, rewrite the question and remove the LTS bits. Make the LTS question a separate post and ask something like "What are the implications to those who receive these PCs of installing 19.10 vs 18.04 LTS? Will they be required to upgrade to receive support here after July?"

Comment: done... leaving the LTS part out... going to install LTS-OEM, user can upgrade if desired :) thanks.