# OEM Installer password

Tags: password, bug-reporting, oem

As I discovered a bug in the Kubuntu 21.10 OEM installer, I would like to have a look into the logs in a different tty.

Unfortunately I can't access the preinstalled oem account as I can't find a password.

Does anbody know if there even is a password set, and if so provide it.
Alternatively could anyone provide a method of opening a terminal in the OEM installation?

Comment: You've provided no release details; but are you talking about *live* media?  The live media is usually user `kubuntu` and from memory no password (I'd try `kubuntu` next).  The live media has no OEM detail; that's provided by the user at first login post-install.

Comment: Thanks for the info, added the version. I am talking about an [OEM installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36671/how-do-i-pre-install-ubuntu-for-someone-oem-install)

Comment: On a new OEM install; no password is set. On initial login the user provides a username/password and then it's set.  None exists until then (ie. it's invalid)

Comment: @guiverc Your comment provides only minimal relation to my initial question, as it only outlines the basic bugreport steps, which are already taken in the report. My question was specifically about finding a method to be able to provide extended information to the already initiated bugreport.

Comment: I don't QA-test OEM installs so have little experience with them.  Thank you for providing the related link (*on bug report*); yes it looks very related; Kubuntu uses a Qt skin over `ubiquity` so it can differ to the other flavors that also use `ubiquity` (the two other Qt5 based flavors use `calamares`). My bug-squad work is unrelated to this support site; I'd have to do a QA-test install of an OEM release to look where details are & I can't see myself doing an OEM install soon (my next QA-tests will be with `calamares` & *canary* so no OEM options exist)