# How to delete files/folders etc

Tags: security, files, delete, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do I have to do before giving away my Ubuntu machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34550/what-do-i-have-to-do-before-giving-away-my-ubuntu-machine)
>   [How to delete file(s) in secure manner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57572/how-to-delete-files-in-secure-manner)

I intend to sell my laptop and therefor I am looking for some solution to my problem. How to get rid of all date in a secure manner? And as well the files which were deleted in the past are throughout some software still accessible. My disc has couple partitions. I don't want others to read my emails, see my photos etc. What is the best way?

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would boot a live CD and wipe the hard drive with scrub

```
sudo apt-get install scrub
sudo scrub -p dod -f  /dev/sda
```

See [man scrub](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/scrub.1.html)

You could use other tools such as dd

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M
```

Or DBAN - http://www.dban.org/

Then re-install Ubuntu. If you wish you can perform a OEM install

[How do I pre-install Ubuntu for someone (OEM install)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36671/how-to-make-an-oem-install)

Answer (score 0):

SHIFT + DELETE erase the file without using Trash, from command line:
shred file